# как найти сумму всех простых делителей числа БЕЗ массива?

Tags: java

как найти сумму всех простых делителей числа БЕЗ массива? java

Comment: Катя, попробуйте сначала ответить на этот вопрос человеческим языком, без кода.

Answer (score 1):

если нет требований к скорости алгоритма, то можно сделать следующее:

1. определяем максимальное число, до которого могут быть делители числа N - оно равно `M = sqrt(N)` (привет решету Эратосфена)
2. делаем цикл I от 2 до М
3. если число N делится на I, то

`N = N / I`

`SUM = SUM + I`

4. повторяем этап 2) до тех пор пока N не будет равно 1
5. `SUM = SUM + 1` (вообще 1 не является простым числом, но иногда его считают)
6. если на этапе 2) не было найдено ни одного делителя, значит число простое и

`SUM = 1 + N`

Немного оптимизации:

1. если на этапе 2) был найден делитель `I`, но новый этап 2) надо начинать не с 2, а с `I`

Comment: Это сумма всех делителей, а нужно только простых.

Comment: @Эникейщик, с какого перепою всех то? например на 4 все равно делиться никогда не будет потому что делится на 2. Т.е. алгоритм каждый этап ищет делитель от 2 до sqrt(N), и после первого найденного начинает следующий этап, таким образом всегда будут только простые делители

Comment: Ну значит некоторые делители будут суммированы несколько раз. Всё равно не то.

Comment: А некоторые наоборот не будут подсчитаны.

Comment: @Эникейщик, а в задаче разве сказано, что простые делители по разу? с какой стати? во всяком случае в теории чисел об этом говорится однозначно и, к примеру, у числа 20 простые делители 2,2,5. А по вашей логике только 2 и 5, так что мне кажется именно вы не правы

Comment: Ссылку дайте на вашу теорию чисел. Моя говорит, что как раз 2 и 5.  И по вашему алгоритму 5 и не подсчитается.

Comment: называется "основная теорема арифметики" - там как раз про единственность с точностью до перестановки разложения на простые множители ;-) НА то, что вы предлагаете - больше на радикал тянет (правда там произведение простых множителей), а счет 5 - лучший контрпример 14 = 2*7, потому что для 20 можно сказать, что доходим до ceil(sqrt(20)), а так согласен - тут ошибся, ну ок, от 2 до N будем двигаться на первом этапе, на каждом следующем от  K до N, где K - множитель, который нашли на прошлом этапе